# Bash - remove all lines beginning with 'P'

Tags: bash

I have a text file that's about 300KB in size. I want to remove all lines from this file that begin with the letter "P". This is what I've been using:

```
> cat file.txt | egrep -v P*
```

That isn't outputting to console. I can use cat on the file without another other commands and it prints out fine. My final intention being to:

```
> cat file.txt | egrep -v P* > new.txt
```

No error appears, it just doesn't print anything out and if I run the 2nd command, new.txt is empty.
I should say I'm running Windows 7 with Cygwin installed.

Comment: Why do you need `egrep`? Is `P` an extended regex?

Comment: qnd: Regex is wrong. `P*` says "match any number (even 0) of `P`" so it matches every single line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Explanation

1. use `^` to anchor your pattern to the beginning of the line ;
2. delete lines matching the pattern using `sed` and the [`d` flag](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30).

## Solution #1

```
cat file.txt | sed '/^P/d'
```

## Better solution

Use `sed`-only:

```
sed '/^P/d' file.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: @MeJ yep but I prefer to remove flag that can be of destructive nature as people sometimes copy/paste command

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

With awk:

```
awk '!/^P/' file.txt
```

#### Explanation

1. The condition starts with an `!` (*negation*), that **negates** the following pattern ;

   - `/^P/` means *"match all lines starting with a capital `P`"*,
2. So, the pattern is negated to *"**ignore lines starting with a capital `P`**"*.
3. Finally, it leverage `awk`'s behavior when `{ … }` (*action block*) is missing, that is to print the record validating the condition.

So, to rephrase, it **ignores lines starting with a capital `P` and print everything else**.

#### Note

`sed` is line oriented and `awk` column oriented. For your case you should use the first one, see Edouard Lopez's reponse.

Comment: As a toy use case for `awk`, say we want to print `<field1>: <field4>` in all uncommented lines (i.e., not starting with `#`). Here we're actually operating on fields instead of just printing the full lines, so `awk` makes sense: `awk '!/^#/ {print $1": "$4}' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use start of line mark and quotes:

```
 cat file.txt | egrep -v '^P.*'
```

`P*` means P zero or more times so together with `-v` gives you no lines

`^P.*` means start of line, then P, and any char zero or more times

Quoting is needed to prevent shell expansion.

This can be shortened to

```
egrep -v ^P file.txt
```

because `.*` is not needed, therefore quoting is not needed and `egrep` can read data from file.

As we don't use extended regular expressions `grep` will also work fine

```
grep -v ^P file.txt
```

Finally

```
grep -v ^P file.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to use `cat file | egrep ...`, this is better: `egrep .... file`.

Comment: The `.*` is superfluous as well. Drop that, and you don't even need to quote. Just use `grep -v ^P "${old_file}" > "${new_file}"`.

Comment: This will make a complete answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` with inplace substitution (for GNU sed, will also for your cygwin)

```
sed -i '/^P/d' file.txt
```

BSD (Mac) sed

```
sed -i '' '/^P/d' file.txt
```

Comment: I do not recommend inplace replacement as it might lead to data-loss. Especially on wide-public site such as SO.

Comment: @EdouardLopez Just use `sed -i .bak -e '/^P/d' file.txt` to create a backup copy

Comment: @l0b0 yep, but it should be avoided when noobs are the target audience

Comment: Noobs will make `sed '/^P/d' file.txt > file.txt` which is even worse :))

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
cat file.txt | egrep -v -e '^P'
```

`-e` indicates expression.

Comment: Unecessary use of cat. `egrep -v -e '^P' file.txt`