# I want to remove all lines in a file that starts with a certain pattern

Tags: bash, sed, printing

My input file contains 3000 lines.

```
system="This is nice"
system="Add some crazy word"
system="Some crazy word"
system="Add another pattern"
system="The parek went home"
system="Add Ola phradse"
system="The car is nice"
```

I want to remove all the lines that have the word Add after system="

So the input file ends up like

```
system="This is nice"
system="Some crazy word"
system="The parek went home"
system="The car is nice"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208931/bash-remove-all-lines-beginning-with-p 

sed '/^system="Add/d' file.txt > new.txt

This should solve your probblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30) in the terminal

```
sed '/^system="Add/ d' < text.txt > newtext.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

**Solution 1st:** By using awk here.

```
awk '!/system="Add/'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Searching for a line which doesn't have system="Add in it, if yes then print the current line.

**Solution 2nd:** BY using grep here.

```
grep -v '^system="Add'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Using grep's `-v` option which will omit all lines where a regex is matched, like I have given a line starting from `system="Add` then skip it.