# delete all lines starting by: INSERT INTO `mdl_logstore_standard_log` VALUES

Tags: sql, linux, command, text-files, moodle

I have a SQL text file on my Linux server, and I need to remove all lines starting by

```
INSERT INTO `mdl_logstore_standard_log`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208931/bash-remove-all-lines-beginning-with-p/17210943).

Following the "Better Solution" in the chosen answer there, you would likely want to consider using [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed). This will delete the lines without needing to open the file.

For your specific case, you can run

```
sed '/^INSERT INTO `mdl_logstore_standard_log`/d' text_file.sql > new_text_file.sql
```

where you'd replace `text_file.sql` and `new_text_file.sql` with your current file and the file with lines deleted. You may also want to consider looking at the `-i` (or equivalent `--in-place`) option if you'd prefer to overwrite your previous file with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with vim. Open the file, type :g and then make sure you run the following:

```
:g/^INSERT INTO `mdl_logstore_standard_log`/d
```

Explanation:
- ^ is the start of the string, here means starts with
- d at the end means delete
- the pattern between the slashes is the pattern to find

If it looks good, hit :w to save your file.